# Is it well defined to create a BackgroundWorker object only referenced by a local variable?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to C# and WPF. I took hours reading online docs and examples to review some code. The code subclasses `System.Windows.Controls.Page` and use `BackgroundWorker` to do background computing.

From what I learned, the desired way to create a `BackgroundWorker` object in this case, is to make it referenced by a class member variable.

E.g.,

```
public class MyPage: System.Windows.Controls.Page
{   
    // Or: backgroundWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker()
    private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;
    ..
}
```

But the code under review creates the object referenced by a local variable.

```
// Inside a class member function
if (someCondition)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork1);
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork2);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(RunWorkerCompleted);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(this.DataContext);
}
```

Is this well defined? Will the object be eligible for GC after `worker` is out of scope since it's the obvious sole reference to the object? Or the framework adds extra reference count(s) due to those asnyc function callbacks?

By "well-defined", I mean the worker object is guaranteed to stay in memory at least until all the callbacks (e.g., `RunWorkerCompleted`) are finished.

Thanks!

Comment: Try it - create a `WeakReference<BackgroundWorker>` and force a GC - see if the object is still alive.

Comment: Yes it will be fine. But if you want a proof - better to test it yourself as suggested above (or inherit from `BackgroundWorker` and add finalizer, then force GC multiple times and see when that finalizer is called).

Comment: It is OK but the double DoWork() is spooky.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Good point. But it's said to be ok that those handlers will be called sequentially in some order. Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313884/is-it-safe-to-run-multiple-dowork-functions-on-a-single-backgroundworker).

Comment: According to [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/thread-is-dead.html), "Friends don’t let friends use Thread. Or BackgroundWorker. It is time for these classes to go the way of “lock (this)” and “Application.DoEvents”."

Comment: The reference only lives for the lifetime of the method so will be gone *very* quickly.  Doesn't matter, the object can't be collected until after the RunWorkerCompleted event fired.  The thread started by RunWorkerAsync() keeps a reference and the last thing it does it get RWC fired.  .NET Framework classes don't have any early collection bugs, System.Threading.Timer is a notable exception.  Having two distinct references that don't refer to the same object is surely a mistake.  Do beware that you have no control over the lifetime of Page and you want to make sure the BGW no longer runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BackgroundWorker` won't be immediately eligible for garbage collection provided that you call the `RunWorkerAsync()` method. You can confirm this yourself using a `WeakReference`:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork1);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(RunWorkerCompleted);
worker.RunWorkerAsync();

WeakReference viewModelWeakReference = new WeakReference(worker);
worker = null;
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
MessageBox.Show(viewModelWeakReference.IsAlive.ToString());
```

Even if you dispose it right after you have called `RunWorkerAsync()`, it will still hang around until it has finished.